# xslt unwanted @part adds in transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, oxygenxml

I'm trying to do a basic XSLT transformation of the first `<p>` tag into a `<head>` tag. It works, but problem is that I use the `<xsl:copy-of>` template for the other `<p>` tag and it results in a `<p part="N">` with this annoying `@part`.

this is the XML tree :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml"
    schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt>
            <title>Title</title>
         </titleStmt>
         <publicationStmt>
            <p>Publication Information</p>
         </publicationStmt>
         <sourceDesc>
            <p>Information about the source</p>
         </sourceDesc>
      </fileDesc>
  </teiHeader>
  <text>
      <body>
         <p>Title</p>
         <p>Some text here.</p>
      </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

this is my XSL stylesheet :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei"
    xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/TEI/teiHeader"/>
    <xsl:template match="/TEI//body">
        <div>
            <head>
                <xsl:value-of select="./p[1]"/>
            </head>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./p[2]"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the result tree is :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
   <head>Title</head>
   <p part="N">Some text here.</p>
</div>
```

I find out that when I remove this statements in the input tree :

```xml
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml"
    schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
```

the `@part` disappears from the output tree. Can you explain me why ? What are all of this `xml-model` ?

I'm using Oxygen XML Editor 24.1 and Saxon-EE 10.6 (same result with Saxon-PE 10.6 and Saxon-HE 10.6).

Thank you !

Comment: The schema probably adds default attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Oxygen Preferences->"XML / XML Parser / RELAX NG" page you can uncheck the "Add default attributes" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The schema has

```
   <define name="att.fragmentable.attribute.part">
      <optional>
         <attribute xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0"
                    name="part"
                    a:defaultValue="N">
            <a:documentation>specifies whether or not its parent element is fragmented in some way, typically by some other overlapping structure: for example a speech which is divided between two or more verse stanzas, a paragraph which is split across a page division, a verse line which is divided between two speakers.</a:documentation>
            <choice>
               <value>Y</value>
               <a:documentation>(yes) the element is fragmented in some (unspecified) respect</a:documentation>
               <value>N</value>
               <a:documentation>(no) the element is not fragmented, or no claim is made as to its completeness</a:documentation>
               <value>I</value>
               <a:documentation>(initial) this is the initial part of a fragmented element</a:documentation>
               <value>M</value>
               <a:documentation>(medial) this is a medial part of a fragmented element</a:documentation>
               <value>F</value>
               <a:documentation>(final) this is the final part of a fragmented element</a:documentation>
            </choice>
         </attribute>
      </optional>
   </define>
```

and `p` elements reference that `att.fragmentable.attribute.part` with i.e.

```
   <define name="p">
      <element name="p">
         <a:documentation xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0">(paragraph) marks paragraphs in prose. [3.1. Paragraphs 7.2.5. Speech Contents]</a:documentation>
         <ref name="macro.paraContent"/>
         <pattern xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
                  id="tei_all-p-abstractModel-structure-p-in-ab-or-p-constraint-report-6">
            <rule context="tei:p">
               <sch:report xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
                           xmlns:rng="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
                           xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
                           test="(ancestor::tei:ab or ancestor::tei:p) and not( ancestor::tei:floatingText |parent::tei:exemplum |parent::tei:item |parent::tei:note |parent::tei:q |parent::tei:quote |parent::tei:remarks |parent::tei:said |parent::tei:sp |parent::tei:stage |parent::tei:cell |parent::tei:figure )">
        Abstract model violation: Paragraphs may not occur inside other paragraphs or ab elements.
      </sch:report>
            </rule>
         </pattern>
         <pattern xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
                  id="tei_all-p-abstractModel-structure-p-in-l-or-lg-constraint-report-7">
            <rule context="tei:p">
               <sch:report xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
                           xmlns:rng="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
                           xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
                           test="(ancestor::tei:l or ancestor::tei:lg) and not( ancestor::tei:floatingText |parent::tei:figure |parent::tei:note )">
        Abstract model violation: Lines may not contain higher-level structural elements such as div, p, or ab, unless p is a child of figure or note, or is a descendant of floatingText.
      </sch:report>
            </rule>
         </pattern>
         <ref name="att.global.attributes"/>
         <ref name="att.declaring.attributes"/>
         <ref name="att.fragmentable.attributes"/>
         <ref name="att.written.attributes"/>
         <empty/>
      </element>
   </define>
```

So it is the RelaxNG schema that defines the attribute `part` with the default value `N`, the XSLT operates on the input tree with the default attribute values added and your `<xsl:copy-of select="./p[2]"/>` copies that `p` element with its attribute.

Depending on your needs you need to either disable the default attribute addition or you need to write XSLT to remove the `part="N"` attribute e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="p/@part[. = 'N']"/>
```

and instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="./p[2]"/>` use `<xsl:apply-templates select="p[2]"/>` and declare/set up the identity transformation with e.g.

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

Comment: There is also an option in Saxon to drop defaulted attributes from the input (`Feature.EXPAND_ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULTS = false`) It doesn't work in all environments (depends on XML parser support) but it should be OK in your case.

Comment: Thank you Martin, now i understand. Thank you too @Michael, i'm gonna try this !